# AWS EC2 keeps shutting down automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to create an API that runs on AWS EC2 t2.micro. The problem I'm having is that my instance keeps shut down automatically every ~3 hours, which could be because of the "session time" of my AWS Educate account (screenshot attached)

[image: was educate]

Is there any way to keep my instance running constantly (for days and even months)?
I am using "tmux", which does seem to keep my API and the EC2 instance running even after my ssh connection is terminated, but the EC2 instance itself still shuts down automatically.

**EDIT:** If it is not possible to keep an EC2 instance of an AWS Educate account running constantly. Is there a way to start a new session automatically when the old instance's session has expired?
(Maybe using a script/using some tools offered by AWS? I'm new to AWS so I don't know if this is possible)

Comment: AWS Educate accounts are monitored and controlled to minimize expenditure. You should contact them at: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't change that?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for checking in. I was wondering if there is a way to start a new AWS Educate Session automatically whenever the old one expires without having to log back in manually each time a Session expires. (therefore technically keeps the EC2 running constantly if I write a script to set up the API for each new instance).
I have been looking around a while but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you **can't change that**. It is explicitly stated in AWS educate docs:

> When your session ends, your resources will be “stopped.” You will be required to re-start your resources when you start a new session.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using AWS Educate you can Create Regular AWS account which provides some services for free for one year. It includes the EC2 instance as well so you don't have to pay anything and you can run for months and year it will never gone down until you manually stop it.

Comment: Sorry, but its terrible idea. EC2 educate is absolutely free and does not require any credit card details.  Sure it has some limits, but it is risk free and you can play with lots of services, which arent covered by aws free tier.